# Two website route to Synology Docker Container

Tags: docker, synology

I have two wordpress website which run in Synology docker container and mounted the port 8080 and 8081 of the host machine,  i want to create two website  `1.wb.com` and `2.wb.com` , how can I route the traffic to Synology docker?

i.e.

```
1.wb.com --CNAME---> Synology NAS ----> proxy to localhost 8080

2.wb.com --CNAME---> Synology NAS ----> proxy to localhost 8081
```

Is it possible to do something like a virtual host and then do proxying?

Need some ideas. Thanks so much!

Comment: Have you checked [Application portal](https://www.synology.com/en-global/knowledgebase/DSM/help/DSM/AdminCenter/application_appportalias)? I think it offers such functionality that you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, thanks to @leopal , the Application Portal helps. There is a Reverse Proxy setting which is exactly what I am looking for.